# In the media Rest API, what is "missing_image_sizes"?

Tags: uploads, media, rest-api

I'm trying to understand the media rest-API. The last item in the schema:

[image: missing_image_sizes]

What is this? Missing *vis-a-vi* what exactly? Is this information used somehow by default?

Reference: [developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Basically, it corresponds to missing thumbnails or custom-sized images in your media library.

And it's (by default) *a private field* in the REST API and the value is one or more [image sizes as returned by `wp_get_registered_image_subsizes()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_registered_image_subsizes/).

And the function which is used with that field is [`wp_get_missing_image_subsizes()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_missing_image_subsizes/) which returns:

> *(array)* An array of the image sub-sizes that are currently defined but don't exist for this image.

So for example, if you added a new image to your library and then — after the image's thumbnail and other custom sizes are generated — you programmatically called [`add_image_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/), then you'd likely see the `missing_image_sizes` field containing the newly added image size when you request the image data through the REST API. E.g.

- Request URL: (GET method)
  `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/123?context=edit&_wpnonce=<nonce>`
- Sample response for *missing_image_sizes*: `"missing_image_sizes":["my_size"]`